# Routing only work with "#" character problem in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular 6 project. And my `app.routes` like below. But, my problem is, I can access only with `localhost:4200/#/Student` instead of `localhost:4200/Student`. Where can be mistake?

**app.routes.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: MenuLayoutComponent, data: { title: 'Menu Layout' }, children: MenuLayoutRoutes }
];

export const AppRoutes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

**menu-layout.routes.ts**

```
export let MenuLayoutRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'Student', component: StudentComponent, canActivate: [RoleGuard] },
  { path: 'University', component: UniversityComponent, canActivate: [RoleGuard] }
];
```

**app.module.ts**

```
imports: [
  AppRoutes
  ]

providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: LoaderInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
```

Comment: By defect that's wouldn't happends, Are you using haslocationStrategies? https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy#example

Comment: I edited my question @Eliseo. My providers like that. Is it true? Because, I couldn't understand HashLocationStrategy means.

Comment: yeah, you can see the problem in the app.module.ts as @Eliseo said, you are using the HashLocationStrategy, what you want to use is PathLocationStrategy

Comment: Shouldn't I use HashLocationStrategy? Because I'm using Primeng. And there is in default. So, I didn't remove. When I remove now, my project didn't work. Should I remove HashLocationStrategy @AxelM

Comment: if you want to get rid of the 'hash' symbol in your url, then yes you definitly have to switch the Location Strategy.
But also you have to configure your server to redirect you to your index.html.
But at least wit the development build you should be able to reach the the route on localhost:4200/Student

Comment: But, when I remove it, my requests isn't going to my service API @AxelM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use `PathLocationStrategy` instead of `HashLocationStrategy` in app.module.ts

### app.module.ts

```
imports: [
  AppRoutes
  ]

providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: LoaderInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
```

For more information regarding LocationStrategy visit https://angular.io/api/common/LocationStrategy